# A hidden exchange account

Tags: gmail, 5.0-lollipop, exchange

Yesterday my Nexus 7 (first gen) upgraded OTA from Android 4.x to 5.0.2 (Lollipop).

After the upgrade completed I opened the Gmail app and it now shows both my normal Google account and my business email account (Microsoft Hosted Exchange).

Yet for my Exchange account I only see the folders in the Gmail app, no messages and no calendar entries.
When I try to delete the account it is simply 'not there' in the list of accounts (under settings -> Personal -> Accounts).
Trying to add the account with the same email address gives the error "Duplicate account".

Perhaps relevant: The company I work for has some policy settings requiring a PIN on the lock screen.

I did find this thread but I'm not willing to root my device just to remove an account.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/lollipop-exchange-account-issues-how-to-t2943172

For me simply being able to delete this Exchange account and creating a new one is good enough for me.

How do I do that?

Comment: I doubt this, but have you checked the account on Android Settings - Accounts (not from GMail)? Edit: Perhaps I misunderstood your statement on "Settings -> Personal -> Accounts". Instead, have you checked the account **from** GMail app (open drawer menu, tap on your account, select "Manage accounts")

Comment: From the GMail settings I only see the Google accounts. From the Android settings I see the Google accounts and a lot of other accounts but not the Exchange account.